# mysql query not working with codeingiter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to run a query in codeigniter. I am getting correct result in mysql, but in codeigniter its giving no output.. Here is my query:

```
   $saleid = $data_row->saleid;
   $billerid = $data_row->biller_id;

if ($billerid == 7) {
    $discount = $data_row->total_discount;
    $query = "select sum(net_unit_price*quantity) as scanning_charge from sma_sale_items where sale_id=" . $saleid;
    $queryres = $this->db->query($query);
    if ($queryres->num_rows > 0) {
        foreach ($queryres->result() as $queryres1) {
            echo print_r($queryres1);
            $scanning_charge = $queryres1->scanning_charge;
        }
    } else {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

I don't know where am going wrong..Its ok with mysql. Can anyone help me to find where I am wrong.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: syntax error in your coding >> echo print_r($queryres1);

Comment: what  error display in your coding ?

Comment: its not working ..even i remove that.

Comment: nothing.. its showing error..

Comment: What is the error? @Aishwaryas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake..

Problem is with $queryres->num_rows(). I forgot to put brackets.

```
            $saleid=$data_row->saleid;
        $billerid=$data_row->biller_id;

        if($billerid==7)
        { 
            $discount = $data_row->total_discount; 
            $query = "select sum(net_unit_price*quantity) as scanning_charge from sma_sale_items where sale_id=".$saleid;

            $queryres = $this->db->query($query);

            if($queryres->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach($queryres->result() as $queryres1)
                {
                    echo print_r($queryres1);
                    $scanning_charge = $queryres1->scanning_charge;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to check error and print your last query:

```
die($this->db->last_query());
```

put your error code in here.

make sure your codeigniter environment is Development to show error code.

Comment: I tried as you said..but not working..its displaying blank.

Comment: your CI environment is development right? cause if not show error then your query code is good, maybe your code to display the output is wrong.

Comment: how about your var $billerid, what is the value? its '7' or not? try print your $billerid. i'm afraid your $billerid value isn't 7.

Comment: its 7 itself..I checked it

Comment: change your code "$queryres->num_rows " to "$queryres->num_rows() "

Answer (score 0):

Try This. may be this will help You.

```
 $result = $this->db->select('SUM(net_unit_price*quantity) as scanning_charge')
            ->from('sma_sale_items')
            ->where('sale_id', $saleid)
            ->get()
            ->result();
    if ($result) {
        foreach ($result as $queryres) {
            echo $scanning_charge = $queryres->scanning_charge;
        }
    } else {
        echo "Record Not Exist";
    }
```